# What is the max message size in Application Insights events?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

telemetryClient.TrackEvent("Hello World!");

I want to know the max message size for this function because i plan to log operational data that can span a few lines sometimes in one go .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For TrackEvent(string eventName), the eventname max length is 512 characters, please take a look at this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-model-event-telemetry#name).